# Segmentation Fault, array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why do I get the `Segmentation Fault` error? I've documented a lot but couldn't clarify this.

```
char * sir=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
char * aux;
int i;

for(i=1;;i++)
{
    fgets(aux, 50, stdin);

    if(strcmp(aux,"END")==0)
        break;
    else
    {
        sir[i]=malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(aux,sir[i]);
    }
}
```

If I use static allocation, then I get an infinite loop.

Comment: No alloc for *aux so UB:(

Comment: 1) not allocated for `aux` 2) `fgets` include newline. `strcmp(aux,"END\n")` instead of. 3) type of `sir` is `char *`.  `char ** sir=malloc(64*sizeof(char*));` instead of. and `strcpy(aux,sir[i]);` --> `strcpy(sir[i],aux);`

Answer (score 1):

Pointer `aux` was not initialized and has indeterminate value

```
char * aux;
```

Thus in this loop the attempt to write data using the pointer

```
for(i=1;;i++)
{
fgets(aux, 50, stdin);
//...
```

results in undefined behaviour of the program.

Maybe it is a typo and you meant `str` instead of `aux`
Nevertheless in any case this statement

```
sir[i]=malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
```

does not make sense.

Also this cpmparison is wrong

```
if(strcmp(aux,"END") == 0)
```

because the string read by using `fgets` can contain a new line character.